# Oracle SQL: Merge select results on top of each other

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Lets say you have two queries. Query **A** results in:

```
  | A | B | C |
  +---+---+---+
  | 1 | 5 | 9 |
  | 2 | 6 | 10|
```

And Query **B** results in:

```
  | A | B | C |
  +---+---+---+
  | 3 | 7 | 11|
  | 4 | 8 | 12|
```

Is it possible to execute the statements in a way to get:

```
  | A | B | C |
  +---+---+---+
  | 1 | 5 | 9 |
  | 2 | 6 | 10|
  | 3 | 7 | 11|
  | 4 | 8 | 12|
```

Would the simpler solution be to join them? Or if it involves using ';' to separate the two selects I'm getting an error using it.

Also, I have tried using `UNION` or `UNION ALL` between the statements but that gives

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

This is being done in Excel's Microsoft query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a UNION statement.

```
SELECT * FROM queryA
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM queryB
```

The WHERE clauses stay with each query, but the ORDER BY moves to the very end.

When you use UNIONs, the name or alias of the column in the top most query becomes the alias for the entire column. So at the end, you would just write something like Order By A where A is your first column name. Make sure you don't have aliases specified in queries other than the top most one.